# This erlang code throws an exception and I don't know why

Tags: ssl, erlang, rabbitmq, flatten

I'm using a Windows certification authority (AD CS) to issue certificates for the participants in a secure connection between a RabbitMQ Windows service and a client.

The Subject of my client certificate is my Distinguished Name (DN) in LDAP:
"CN=John Ruiz,CN=Users,DC=devexample,DC=com"

When I attempt to establish this connection, the server throws an exception and closes the connection and I see this erlang stack trace in the rabbit log:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 30-Dec-2011::10:33:24 ===
exception on TCP connection <0.331.0> from 10.1.30.70:52269
{channel0_error,starting,
    {error,{case_clause,[{printableString,"Users"},
                         {printableString,"John Ruiz"}]},
                         'connection.start_ok',
                         [{rabbit_ssl,find_by_type,2,[]},
                         {rabbit_auth_mechanism_ssl,init,1,[]},
                         {rabbit_reader,handle_method0,2,[]},
                         {rabbit_reader,handle_method0,3,[]},
                         {rabbit_reader,handle_input,3,[]},
                         {rabbit_reader,recvloop,2,[]},
                         {rabbit_reader,start_connection,7,[]},
                         {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                             [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}}
```

Looking through the last two lines in the stack trace, I found the two files involved:

1. [rabbit_ssl.erl](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-server/file/ca0392ca0fc1/src/rabbit_ssl.erl)
2. [rabbit_auth_mechanism_ssl.erl](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-auth-mechanism-ssl/file/7eb9b73edebb/src/rabbit_auth_mechanism_ssl.erl)

The problem is that I've neither read nor written erlang before, so I don't know why find_by_type is throwing an exception.  My best guess is that since there are two CN=* elements in the list of relative DNs (RDNs), that the result of the call to lists:flatten is an array whereas the expected result is a scalar.

Can someone familiar with erlang please confirm or correct my assumption?  If you see a way in which this code could be improved to handle the case I've just described (instead of throwing an exception), I would really appreciate it so that I can suggest it on the RabbitMQ mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct. It crashes because there are two CN=* elements. Looking at the code it seems like a lot of it depends on there only being one CN. CN itself is used as the username for the ssl session I think so having multiple makes little sense.

Comment: While I agree that having two CNs makes little sense, that's the way it works for Windows.  Domain Users get created in CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=tld which means that users will have a DN containing two CN elements.

Comment: hmm, strange. If you want to just ignore the first CN you can add [_,CN] to the case instead of [CN] in find_by_type. But more of a temporary fix than anything you would want to have in production.

Comment: I wouldn't want to outright ignore it.  openssl-based certs would only have one CN element.  As a temporary fix, I'd prefer to first check to see if the array has more than one element and, if so, simply use the first element.  What would that code look like?

Comment: [CN|_] would give you the first CN and ignore the rest if they exist. That would be give the CN to be "Users" for the example you gave.